# Open and edit *.gsheet file in excel

Tags: google-sheets

I have downloaded "Google Drive" application to my Windows 7 Ultimate Machine.

Now When I go to the folder and see my spreadsheet it is in some weird format called "*.gsheet". Now this file is not being opened by Excel(As if I need to mention that!!)

Now I want a solution, Such that:

1. Either the file is stored as a normal `*.xlsx` or `*.odf` file so that I can edit whenever I want to and as soon as I am done, The file will be synced to my drive immediately.(I have an internet connection of course)
2. Or A software that can open this kind of file and give the same kind of functionality(it is alright if it is slightly less than excel.) as excel.

**Please** help me with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened a ticket by Google for a similar issue.
The thing is Google has no serious procedure to deal with that...
So what I can advise you best, is for your option 2)

Then you will be able to open your synchronized *.gsheet file with your Chrome browser when you will be offline.

To do this, you have to perform two procedures :

1. Follow [this procedure](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/2809731?hl=en) to turn on Google Drive offline
2. *Enable each gsheet file to be available offline (I know it's weird and boring to do it for each file).* =>

   To do this second procedure, you have to go to GoogleSheet [docs.google.com/spreadsheets/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/). It will list all your gsheet files. Then click on the ... (three dot) on the right hand side of one file, and tick "available offline". Repeat this for every of your gsheet files.

Then reboot your PC and disconnect from Internet.
Double click you *.gsheet file. It should open Chrome and let you update your file. The next time you'r connected to Internet, it will update it on GDrive.

Oh ! One more thing... If you have several computers, you'll have to repeat both procedure for each device...

Answer (score 2):

From the browser, you will have to manually download the spreadsheet as the format you want (.ods, .xls, .csv). You can read more details [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2423534?hl=en). The issue is then that as you edit the file that you downloaded, it won't make changes to the .gsheet file. For that reason, you may want to work on the .xls file and store it in your drive as an .xls (or .csv, .ods, etc)

Comment: In case someone sent you a .gsheet and you need to get to the Google doc: open the .gsheet file in a text editor like Notepad. There you will find the URL of the Google doc. From there you can download the file as .xls, etc.