# Import or Open gsheet file in Google Docs or Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I have a local file named `timeline.gsheet` , which is [apparently generated by Google Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248782/open-and-edit-gsheet-file-in-excel).  How do I import, edit, and save this file in Google Docs?

**From Google Sheets:**

File -> Import -> Upload

Import error
timeline.gsheet

Sorry, that file type isn't supported for import.
Supported types are: csv, txt, tsv, tab, html, htm, xls, xlsx, xlsm, xlt, xltm, xltx, ods.

**Upload to Google Docs:**

Shows up as timeline.gsheet with a little package icon next to it.
When opened, it shows "3 items":

- Folder named `_rels`
- Folder named `xl`
- Document named `[Content_Types].xml`

Google Docs does not appear to handle a gsheet file when opened in this way.

`gsheet` file format may also be similar to `gdoc` format.

Comment: The local system does not recognize the filetype when double-clicking.  When uploaded and "opened" in Google Drive, it shows the 3 items detailed above.